# How to call subclass method through superclass instance in java?

Tags: java

Suppose we have a superclass such as

```
public class Superclass  
{  
    public void method1() {  
        // do something 
    }  
}// end Superclass
```

and a Subclass such as

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass
{
    public void method1() {
        //override method1() of Superclass
    }

    public void method2() {
        // bla bla bla
    }
}// end Subclass
```

Now consider the following code

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Superclass obj = new Subclass();
}
```

I'm looking for a way to call method2() through variable obj. Is there any way to do this? If so, how can this task be done?

Comment: You would have to cast it: `((Subclass) obj).method2()`

Comment: You can't without casting. Subtyping 'extends' the supertype hierarchically. This does not go 'upwards' from child to parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do so, you have to cast it obj to `SubClass`:

```
((Subclass) obj).method2();
```

Comment: @Alnitak: Not in Java. Are you thinking of C++ class slicing? That doesn't apply here. The runtime type will actually be `Subtype` even though the compile-time type is `Supertype`.

Comment: @Alnitak - it will compile, with a warning. this is obviously, as any down-casting, should be done with caution and only when you know for sure (or verify with `instanceof`) that obj is indeed SubClass. but this is a theoretical question of how can it be done, and this is how it can

Comment: @NirLevy: The Java compiler will not issue a warning for a narrowing cast. If the cast is invalid at runtime a `ClassCastException` will be thrown instead.

Comment: Damn - I misread the constructor call - I thought the OP was instantiating a `SuperClass` object.

Comment: @Alnitak: Ah yes. If the runtime type actually is `Superclass` then the code is guaranteed to throw a `ClassCastException`. If you know the type is actually `Subclass` (e.g. if you've just done an `instanceof` check) then the narrowing cast is safe. But even if it's safe it may not be a good idea, since users of `Superclass` shouldn't have to care about its implementations.

Answer (score 3):

As the comment above points out, if you need to do this it may indicate that your classes are not modeled correctly.

Often a better approach would be to provide a default implementation in the supertype and simply have the subtype override the implementation.

For example:

```
public class Superclass {
  public void method1() {
    // method1 implementation
  }

  public void method2() {} // empty implementation
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
  @Override
  public void method2() {
    // do subclass stuff
  }
}
```

Then at your call site you would just need to do:

```
Superclass obj = new Subclass();
// Since the runtime type is Subclass, this calls Subclass's
// implementation of method2
obj.method2();
```