# How to use interface method implemented by a class which also extends another class?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, interface

I have some classes named as "Account", "CurrentAccount", "SavingsAccount". "CurrentAccount" and "SavingsAccount" extends "Account", Also "CurrentAccount" implements an interface "TaxDeduction". "TaxDeduction" has method by name of "deductTax()", whose body is defined in "CurrentAccount".

```
public class CurrentAccount extends Account implements TaxDeduction {
  public void deductTax() {
   double tax = (super.getBalance() * taxRate) / 100;
    super.setBalance(super.getBalance() - tax);
    }
}
```

```
public interface TaxDeduction {
    static double taxRate=8.5;
    void deductTax();
}
```

Now I made an array of Account[] which stores objects of "CurrentAccount" & "SavingsAccount". When I retrieve a "CurrentAccount" Object in main class and try to use "deductTax()" method then I get error that "deductTax()" method is not resolved in "Account" whereas I can use all other normal methods in "CurrentAccount" class. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Use instanceof and cast. Or keep a separate list with the Deductions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to call subclass method through superclass instance in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948318/how-to-call-subclass-method-through-superclass-instance-in-java)

Comment: @daniu I am new to java and just started learning it, I don't understand what you said, can you kindly elaborate your suggestion?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can call all other subclass and also super class methods but problem is only with abstract method "deductTax()" from implemented interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is a statically typed language. If you have a variable of type `Account`, you can only call methods defined in `Account` (and its superclasses and implemented interfaces). Attempting to call a method not defined in `Account` will result in a compiletime error, because as far as the compiler is concerned, the value held in the variable is only an `Account`.

So, the compiler will not allow you to call methods of `TaxDeduction`, then either `Account` (or one of its superclasses) must implement it, or you must check if the instance held by the variable is an instance of `TaxDeduction` (using `instanceof`), and then cast to `TaxDeduction` and call the method.

When you use `instanceof` you check the actual type at runtime, and the cast tells the compiler that you're sure it's actually a `TaxDeduction`, so you can call the method(s) defined in `TaxDeduction`. When you're wrong about the type in the cast, you'll get a runtime exception, `ClassCastException` (which is why it's recommended to use `instanceof` before casting).

In other words, something like:

```java
Account[] accounts = ...;
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (account instanceof TaxDeduction) {
        ((TaxDeduction) account).deductTax();
    }
}
```

Or in Java 16 and higher ([JEP 394](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394)):

```java
Account[] accounts = ...;
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (account instanceof TaxDeduction td) {
        td.deductTax();
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked and its indeed instance of TaxDeduction and by casting to TaxDeduction I can also call the method as you told above, but I am still confused that why do I need to cast to TaxDeduction and can't directly use deductTax() ?

Comment: @MohsinZubair Java is a statically typed language. If you have a variable of type `Account`, then even if you have an object of type `CurrentAccount` assigned to that variable, you can only access methods defined in type `Account`. Attempting to call a method not defined in `Account` will result in a compiletime error, because as far as the compiler is concerned, the value held in the variable **is** only an `Account`. When you use `instanceof` you check the actual type at runtime, and the cast tells the compiler that you're sure it's actually a `TaxDeduction`.

Comment: @MohsinZubair When you're wrong about the type in the cast, you'll get a runtime exception, `ClassCastException` (which is why it's recommended to use `instanceof` before casting).

Comment: thanks for clarification, now I understand it perfectly.